# PowerBuilder MySQL Connection

Tags: mysql, powerbuilder

How do I connect my PowerBuilder to MySQL?

First I would like to use Database Painter to conenct to my local MySQL Database so I can create my datawindows.

Then I would like to make a DSNLESS connection so I can just add .ini and ProfileString my connection.

Comment: You'll probably need jdbc driver for this. Try downloading mysql jdbc driver and then follow [this](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=47902) instructions.

Comment: may I ask what for? I am using ODBC to connect temporarily but I needed to minimize client interaction to Administration Settings and Control Panel.

Comment: Because ODBC connection sometimes becomes problematic for Powerbuilder connection. We were using ODBC for our DB connectivity. Everything was working quite well. We had our query running and all, and the speed was also fast. Then, suddenly, when we started executing long queries in our database, connections started to drop out with no apparent reasons. We tried everything we could, such as changing timeout intervals, changing drivers, but it didn't work. We then switched to jdbc driver and it worked well. I don't know if latest ODBC drivers solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for that, This is using MySQL? can you give me a sample of your connection string? and also what type in DB Painter did you use.

Comment: Sorry I can't provide a sample for my connection string at the moment, as I've worked on that project a long time ago and currently I don't have access to the code base. We used the database painter that comes with Powerbuilder 9.0

Comment: Ok. thanks. i will try to review the mysql jdbc driver. but as of the moment i cannot grasp how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a DSN-less connection, I pulled this syntax from http://www.connectionstrings.com/

[ODBC](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/):

```
SQLCA.DBMS = "ODBC"
SQLCA.DBParm = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;"
```

Note that you might have to tweak the version number (5.1) to match the version you download.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Profile Transporter3
SQLCA.DBMS = "JDBC"
SQLCA.LogPass = "tss"
SQLCA.LogId = "root"
SQLCA.AutoCommit = False
SQLCA.DBParm = "Driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',URL='jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb'"
```

the only thing is you need to set classpath of the jar file for which i posted in Linked in please refer

now it connect to MySQL the big problem arises is Ignore space after Function name
I dont understand how to set option for this in JDBC for odbc there is option. i go through documentation
of connector J but no such option. This problem arises only for PowerBuilder so i request you if you know the solution please provide it.

Answer (score 0):

i resolve this issue mysql option -i or --ignore-spaces is going to work so i set that option in configuration files i.e. my.ini

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,IGNORE_SPACE"

stop MySQL service and then started it works smoothly

Answer (score 0):

You have to configurare db profile like servername, database, etc., . In this preview tabpage check the connection and copy &paster the commands in application open event.

By PB team